# Real time python app that works on a database

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL with python and the SQL database is such that rows are added regularly. At present, the python program does not know if new data has been added (I used psycopg2 to read rows. But it reads till the end of rows and stops). How can I let my python program constantly search if new data has been added? Or can I let postgreSQL trigger python when a new row is added?

This is what I have currently:

```
def get_data():
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(database="yardqueue", user="postgres", password="abcd", host="localhost", port="5432")
    except:
        print "Could not open database"
    cur = connect.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id,position FROM container")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print "ID = ", row[0]
        print "Position = ", row[1]
```

As you see, when I run this, it stops once variable 'row' reaches the last row.

**EDIT**: Is there a way I can keep my python code running for a specified amount of time? If so, I can make it go through the database until I kill it.

Comment: why would you need to find out if new data were added?

Comment: try cursor.rowcount

Comment: @AzatIbrakov because, this is a project about setting container position on a yard. The container data is added constantly and I want python to allocate the particular position for each data

Comment: @HaifengZhang row count is constant for a particular run of the script right?

Comment: you can make infinite loop with [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) and check if previous rows count has changed

Comment: which workflow are you expecting: checking for new records, sleeping some time, checking again and inform user if some were added, ...?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov that will be perfect.

Comment: there could be deletions of `container` records?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov no.

Comment: note that given solution will print out all records each time rows count changes

Comment: maybe we should print only new records?

Comment: also: is `id` an orderable (e. g. has integer type) primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to check out new records we can write (assuming there are no deletions in `container` table):

```
from time import sleep

import psycopg2

IDLE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 2


def get_data():
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(database="yardqueue", user="postgres",
                                   password="abcd", host="localhost",
                                   port="5432")
    except:
        print "Could not open database"
        # TODO: maybe we should raise new exception? 
        # or leave default exception?
        return
    cur = connect.cursor()
    previous_rows_count = 0
    while True:
        cur.execute("SELECT id, position FROM container")
        rows_count = cur.rowcount
        if rows_count > previous_rows_count:
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print "ID = ", row[0]
                print "Position = ", row[1]
            previous_rows_count = rows_count
        sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS)
```

if we want to process only new records we can add [ordering by](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-order.html) id and [offset](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html) like

```
from time import sleep

import psycopg2

IDLE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 2


def get_data():
    try:
        connect = psycopg2.connect(database="yardqueue", user="postgres",
                                   password="abcd", host="localhost",
                                   port="5432")
    except:
        # TODO: maybe we should raise new exception? 
        # or leave default exception?
        print "Could not open database"
        return
    cur = connect.cursor()
    rows_count = 0
    while True:
        cur.execute("SELECT id, position FROM container "
                    # sorting records by id to get new records data
                    # assuming that "id" column values are increasing for new records
                    "ORDER BY id "
                    # skipping records that we have already processed
                    "OFFSET {offset}"
                    .format(offset=rows_count))
        rows_count = cur.rowcount
        if rows_count > 0:
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                print "ID = ", row[0]
                print "Position = ", row[1]
        sleep(IDLE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS)
```

Comment: Yes. id is a primary key

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a database has no notion of insertion order, so you as the designer must provide an explicit order. If you do not, the order of the rows you fetch (using a new cursor) may change at any time.

Here a possible way is to have a `serial` field in your table. PostgreSQL implements a serial field through a *sequence*, which guarantees that each new inserted row gets a serial number greater than all currently existing ones. But:

- there can be holes if a transaction requires a serial number and is aborted
- if multiple concurrent transactions insert a serial field, the order of the serial field will be the order of the *insert* commands, not the order of the *commit* commands. That means that race conditions can result in a wrong order. But it is fine if you have only one writer in the database

An alternative way is to use an insertion date field - the inserting application has to manage it explicitely or you can use a trigger to set it tranparently. PostgreSQL timestamp have a microsecond precision. That means that many rows can have same insertion date value if they are inserted at the same time. Your Python script should read the time before opening a cursor  and fetch all rows with an insertion time greater than its last run time. But here again you should care of race conditions...